# The fastest way to get all permutations of a range without having consecutive neighbours in python

Tags: python, list, performance, range, permutation

I want to get all permutations of any range with length n, starting from 0 and ending on n (`range(n)`) that don't have consecutive numbers.

Example: `[0,1,2,3,4]`

There the permutations should look like for example `[0,2,4,1,3]` or `[3,1,4,2,0]`

My current approach just gets all existing permutations and just skips these ones that have consecutive numbers in them.:

```
import itertools
all = itertools.permutations(range(n))
  
for e in all:
  double = True
      
  for a, b in zip(e, e[1:]):
    if abs(int(a)-int(b)) <= 1:
      double = False
      break

    if double == True:
      # do sth
```

the problem I have with this code is that the number of permutations rises by a lot really fast and when it comes to ranges of 10 or bigger, I spend most of my time just skipping permutations and waisting time. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

And another question: If that can be done faster, is there then also a more time efficient implementation where the elements must be at least 2 units appart? That the line `if abs(int(a)-int(b)) <= 1` is changed to `if abs(int(a)-int(b)) <= 2` and only permutations like `[0,4,1,5,2,6,3]` are accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following recursive function does the trick. It constructs only the wanted permutations. It accepts a `dst` argument indicating the minimum distance that must be *exceeded* by the next addition taken from set `rem` to the end of list `beg`.

```
# comp_perm: complete the permutation
# beg: beginning of sequence
# rem: set of remaining (still unused) numbers
# dst: integer indicating distance that must be *exceeded*
def comp_perm(beg: list, rem: set, dst: int) -> list:
  if (not rem): # check whether rem is the empty set
    return [beg]
  return_lst = [] # list of sequences starting with beg
  for num in rem:
    if (not beg) or abs(num - beg[-1]) > dst:
      return_lst.extend(comp_perm(beg+[num], rem-{num}, dst))
  return return_lst

comp_perm([], set(range(5)), 1)
# [[0, 2, 4, 1, 3], [0, 3, 1, 4, 2], [1, 3, 0, 2, 4], ...]
```

The for-loop checks for every potential addition `num` whether the distance between it and the last element of `beg` is *bigger than* `dst`. If `beg` is the empty list (`not beg`), no such check is necessary.

Here is how it is intended to be used in full generality:

```
comp_perm([5, 9], {7, 11, 100}, 3)
# [[5, 9, 100, 11, 7], [5, 9, 100, 7, 11]]
```

---

Calling

```
for tpl in comp_perm([], set(range(5)), 1):
  print(tpl)
```

prints the following:

```
[0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
[0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
[1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 0, 3]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 0, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 4, 0, 3, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 3, 0]
[3, 0, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 1, 4, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 4, 2, 0]
[4, 1, 3, 0, 2]
[4, 2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Calling

```
for tpl in comp_perm([], set(range(6)), 2):
  print(tpl)
```

prints the following:

```
[2, 5, 1, 4, 0, 3]
[3, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2]
```

Your desired example `[0,4,1,5,2,6,3]` is in the results for `7` numbers with `dst` set to `2`:

```
[0,4,1,5,2,6,3] in comp_perm([], set(range(7)), 2)
# True
```

Enlarging the set of numbers to permute leads quickly to long lists:

```
len(comp_perm([], set(range(5)), 2))
# 0
len(comp_perm([], set(range(6)), 2))
# 2
len(comp_perm([], set(range(7)), 2))
# 32
len(comp_perm([], set(range(8)), 2))
# 368

len(comp_perm([], set(range(7)), 3))
# 0
len(comp_perm([], set(range(8)), 3))
# 2
len(comp_perm([], set(range(9)), 3))
# 72
len(comp_perm([], set(range(10)), 3))
# 1496
```

---

By the way, the [answer by Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75848009/2057969) makes excellent use of [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def custom_permutations(lst, apart=2, indices=None):
    if not indices:
        indices = []
    elif len(indices) == len(lst):
        yield [lst[i] for i in indices]
        return

    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if not indices or (i not in indices and abs(lst[indices[-1]] - v) > apart):
            yield from custom_permutations(lst, apart=apart, indices=indices + [i])


lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

for p in custom_permutations(lst, apart=1):
    print(p)
```

Prints:

```py
[0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
[0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
[1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 0, 3]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 0, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 4, 0, 3, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 3, 0]
[3, 0, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 1, 4, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 4, 2, 0]
[4, 1, 3, 0, 2]
[4, 2, 0, 3, 1]
```

---

For:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
apart = 2
```

Prints:

```
[0, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4]
[0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3]
[1, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2, 5]
[1, 4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 3]
[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 0, 4]
[2, 5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4]
[2, 5, 0, 4, 1, 6, 3]
[2, 5, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6]
[2, 5, 1, 4, 0, 6, 3]
[2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 0, 4]
[2, 6, 3, 0, 4, 1, 5]
[2, 6, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4]
[3, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6]
[3, 0, 4, 1, 6, 2, 5]
[3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4]
[3, 0, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4]
[3, 6, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2]
[3, 6, 1, 4, 0, 5, 2]
[3, 6, 2, 5, 0, 4, 1]
[3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 0]
[4, 0, 3, 6, 1, 5, 2]
[4, 0, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1]
[4, 1, 5, 0, 3, 6, 2]
[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 0, 3]
[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 0]
[4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3]
[4, 1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 2]
[5, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6, 2]
[5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3]
[5, 2, 6, 3, 0, 4, 1]
[6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 0, 3]
[6, 3, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2]
```